# How do I configure StaticParser using expression generator as of angular.dart 0.9.9?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

For my production releases, I have been using the expression extractor to generate a file containing expressions that are being used by my templates.  When in production, I was configure the StaticParser like so:

```
import '../gen/expression_cache.gen.dart' as expression_cache;
...
module.type(Parser, implementedBy: StaticParser);
module.value(StaticParserFunctions, expression_cache.functions()); // <-- this no longer works
```

Something has changed with how the expressions are generated, as the line configuring `StaticParserFunctions` no longer works.  The `functions()` method no longer exists.  So I'm wondering, what is the correct way to do this as of angular 0.9.9?

Answer (score 0):

Is far as I know the Angular Dart tutorial is pretty much up to date.
https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_07/web/initializer-prod.dart
https://angulardart.org/tutorial/09-ch07-deploying-your-app.html (search for generator)

Comment: `initializer-prod.dart` is using the obsolete `functions()` method too.

Comment: I didn't encounter this problem yet. Maybe you find here what you are looking for https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/test/core/parser/static_parser_spec.dart